# Why does ranked-choice voting give such high preference to the second choice of the least-favored candidate's voters?

Tags: voting-systems, ranked-choice-voting

Ranked choice voting is in the news lately because of the big mess New York City has made of implementing it in its Democratic primaries for the mayoral race.  But in the talk about how it works, one point strikes me as a bit odd.

As I understand it, RCV counts up the first-choice candidate votes.  If no one reaches 50%, whoever got the least number is washed out, and their voters' second-place candidates are promoted to first, the numbers are re-counted, and the cycle is repeated until someone reaches a majority.

While this seems like a good system at first glance, the implementation has a strange quirk in it: the people whose second-choice votes get redistributed first -- and are therefore the most likely to influence the final results -- are the ones who voted for the least popular candidate, or in other words, *the ones whose preferences are the least representative of the overall will of the electorate.*

What's the rationale for giving that group disproportionate power in choosing the winning candidate?  That seems a bit counterintuitive.

Comment: I think there is a logic fallacy at work. Just because one voted for the least popular candidate, this does not make one less representative of total voters. 5% of voters is still 5% of voters, no matter whom they voted for in first rank.

Comment: This like saying the only important person in a sporting event is the one that scored the winning point, ignoring that it is only the winning point because of the contributions of all the other actions that happened before it.

Comment: I agree that there is a logical fallacy going on here. If three voters are voting between two candidates at a table and voter 1 says he votes for A, voter 2 says he votes for B, and voter 3 says he votes for A, did voter 3 have "disproportionate power in choosing the winning candidate"? What if the vote order was reversed?

Comment: The other way to look at this would be to say that in traditional elections, the votes of people who voted for the least popular candidate(s) had *no influence on the result at all* -- it was as if they hadn't even voted. That's the source of the common saying that voting third-party is "throwing your vote away".  RCV corrects this by allowing a person to vote for an unlikely candidate, and then if that candidate is eliminated, have his vote "fall back" to another choice instead, so that every voter's vote can influence the result of the election, regardless of which candidate(s) they prefer.

Comment: Of all the preference-voting systems that exist, IRV is pretty close to the worst. But its simplicity gives it a kind of "consumer confidence" cachet.

Comment: @Manziel Voting for the least popular candidate does in fact make one less representative than the average voter.

Comment: @Acccumulation Not true at all. Sometimes the most representative candidate gets the least first-preference votes because of vote splitting.

Comment: So you are saying voting for Z then A, vs for A first, somehow gives you more voting power when you end up voting for A either way?  Makes no sense.

Comment: @rtaft Yes, that does make no sense, but that's not what I'm saying.

Comment: @MasonWheeler Are you saying since people voted for Z and lost, they shouldn't be allowed a second vote, or a third or a forth because they get to cast more votes than everyone else?

Comment: @endolith The subject was whether people who vote for the lowest ranked candidate are less representative, not whether the candidate is.

Comment: @Acccumulation The purpose of a voting system is to elect the candidate who best represents the voters, not to give votes only to the "most representative" voters.

Answer (score 57):

There's three main reasons:

1. **It's simple.** Voters are giving instructions, "I want this candidate, and if I can't have them, I want this one instead, .... n." Voters understand how their vote will be processed without having to do any maths.
2. **It reflects a reasonable approximation+ of strategic voting.** In single-vote systems, people often vote against their own preference, because the candidate they prefer doesn't have a realistic chance of winning. (This is, in fact, one of the major problems with single-vote systems.) RCV allows a more accurate picture of their actual preferences, and before their unusual tastes are ruled out of the possibility space, their unearned support for a given strategic-choice candidate is taken out of the picture.

+: This is an oversimplification and applies only to the case of voters whose preferred candidate is dead last (or close thereto). See [this link](https://electowiki.org/wiki/Favorite_betrayal_criterion#Instant-runoff_voting) for more detail about the concept of strategic voting. (Credit to @eclipz905 for the link.)

3. **Your estimate of their influence is likely too high.** Votes are distributed to 2nd choices at the individual vote level. So when candidate #5 is eliminated, the - let's say 1,000 - votes they earned are not awarded to a single other candidate. Instead, they are allocated according to each of those 1,000 voters' preferences. Depending on the texture of the field, it is entirely possible that all four remaining candidates receive a share of that 1,000. It's also possible that some voters did not indicate a 2nd choice, in which case those votes drop out of the electorate that cycle entirely.

In short, this group does not receive disproportionate power. You are correct that they are the main beneficiaries of RCV systems - they're now allowed to rationally vote for the candidate they *actually* prefer, instead of being forced to make a strategic choice between two candidates they like less (at best).

Under single-vote systems, their preferences are essentially being quashed.

Comment: _"... they're now allowed to rationally vote for the candidate they actually prefer ..."_. This is not accurate. Under RCV (a.k.a. instant runoff voting [IRV]), voting for one's sincere preferences is only safe if the preferred candidate is very strong, or very weak. In competitive scenarios, there is strong incentive to vote strategically. This is specified with the [Favorite Betrayal Criterion](https://electowiki.org/wiki/Favorite_betrayal_criterion#Instant-runoff_voting) and visualized [here](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=JtKAScORevQ)

Comment: @eclipz905 Thank you for that link! In the specific case being discussed, the subject's preferred candidate is very weak, in fact they're dead last.  But what you bring up is important context. I will add to my answer.

Comment: What's funny is that approval voting is even simpler to understand and tabulate, and never requires people to cast votes contrary to their true preferences, but for some reason people aren't comfortable with the idea of being able to cast more than one vote despite the fact that at most one of the votes a person casts in a single-winner election could affect the election (votes for anyone other than the final winner have no effect).  Someone who prefers A to B but B to C may be stuck in a quandary as to whether to mark the ballot for both A and B, or just A, but neither ballot would be...

Comment: ...inconsistent with the person's preferences.

Comment: @supercat - I've wondered that myself.  I even asked one of the main people from an organization lobbying their state government for RCV why not approval voting instead, and got a kindof non-answer back.

Comment: @Bobson The only possible argument for RCV is "momentum". Unfortunately it's a pretty effective argument

Comment: @supercat Approval voting assumes a voter has candidates they like, and candidates they hate with no candidates they hate a little less.

Comment: @supercat: RCV favors the big parties over the small parties. The big parties are perfectly happy to see RCV take votes away from the small parties and reallocate them to the big parties, but they would be very unhappy if e.g. the Schulze method decided that "This centrist is the Condorcet winner, even though 90% of the electorate voted for somebody else as first choice." They don't want a *good* electoral system as much as they just want to get rid of the spoiler effect from 3rd party candidates. In other words: Approval voting creates the risk of a third party actually winning!

Comment: "Your estimate of their influence is likely too high".  It might be mentioned to further emphasize this point that, as people whose first-choice was the least popular candidate, they are by definition the smallest group within the voters already (when parsed by first choices), and thus the group whose votes will have the least potential influence when re-allocated.

Comment: @IanRingrose: Someone who votes for A and B but not C indicates that A outranks C and B outranks C, without stating any preference for A versus B.  Someone who votes only for A says that A outranks B and A outranks C, without stating any preference for B versus C.  Failing to say which of two candidates is better doesn't imply a belief that they are equally good--merely that the difference between them is less than the difference between some other pair of candidates.  If one casts an approval ballot, one of two things will happen:

Comment: @IanRingrose: Either one of the approved candidate will win, in which case the whichever ranking criterion was most important will be satisfied, or no manner of voting would have allowed the most important ranking criterion to be satisfied.

Answer (score 40):

This type of ranked-choice voting is effectively like doing a bunch of run-off elections all at once. In other words, assuming there are five candidates (A, B, C, D, and E), we ***could*** do the following:

1. Hold an election
2. If there is no winner, scratch off the worst candidate (E) and hold a run-off

   - those who voted for A, B, C, and D will cast the same vote, but E's supporters will have to choose from the remaining four
3. If there's no winner, scratch off the *new* worst candidate (D) and hold another run-off

   - those who voted for A, B, C will cast the same vote, but D's supporters (including those who might have originally voted for E) will have to choose from the remaining three
4. Repeat runoffs until a clear winner emerges

On a ranked-choice ballot, we put who we want to win as the first choice, and who we would vote for if our guy got scratched as the second choice, who we would vote for if both our choices got scratched as the third choice... The only difference from a series of recall elections is that we don't get the opportunity to change our minds if our first-chosen candidate survives into the run-off. But not that many people *would* change their minds — changing first-preferences reflects either deep apathy or deep strategy — so that doesn't seem to be a great hardship.

It may look as though we are giving excess power to those who support the least popular candidate, but in fact we are just asking them to choose again, as though the candidate they want had never run at all. It's as fair and balanced as any other first-past-the-post ballot; we're just saving time and money on do-overs.

Comment: This is an interesting perspective, but the counterpoint is that the runoff itself can add new and relevant information.  I know there have been times I've wished I could change my vote after seeing how a candidate reacted to the results of a narrow election; I can't help but think there are lots of people who would say the same.  Is it really a good idea to force the election to be decided on incomplete information?

Comment: Indeed one of the many names of the system (and the one which seems to have been used on Wikipedia) is Instant-runoff https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Instant-runoff_voting.

Comment: @origimbo: A name I very much prefer over “ranked-choice voting”, on the grounds that there are other methods based on ranking choices that are totally unrelated to IRV (e.g., Borda, Condorcet, and their numerous variants).

Comment: @dan04 but the most common implementation of "true" runoffs is to eliminate _every_ candidate except for the top two and then ask everyone to vote again.  Calling the system "instant runoff" could lead people to conclude that it somehow works similarly.

Comment: @phoog It kinda does, in that your influence on who is elected ultimately comes down to the order in which you rank the final two candidates (regardless of where in your rankings those two occur). It's just that the top two candidates for the final "runoff" are identified using 2nd, 3rd, etc preference votes as well, instead of only using 1st preference votes.

Comment: @masonwheeler The counterpoint to your counterpoint is that it'd be very easy for a series of runoff elections to take longer than the actual term does.

Comment: The other difference between IRV and traditional run-offs is that in a traditional run-off, not everybody who voted in the first election will vote in the run-offs.  Turnout tends to drop off with each subsequent round of run-offs, as not everybody wants to or can wait in line *multiple* times for the same election.  So even the people whose candidate *didn't* get eliminated in the first rounds might just not show up at all the next time.  With IRV, you only need to take time off to vote once, so this isn't an issue.

Comment: This answer addresses a flaw in the question text: it is not valid to argue that ballots who ranked the worst candidate 1st have a disproportionate effect on the result: with 4 or more candidates, there are 2 or more runoffs, and the phrase "the worst candidate" denotes a different candidate each time.

Comment: @MasonWheeler That way lies madness.  When do you know information is no longer incomplete?  All elections are decided on incomplete information.

Comment: @MichaelRichardson - exactly! You beat me to the punch.

Comment: @MichaelRichardson Isn't that what recalls are for?

Comment: @MasonWheeler At best, you can just say that there is additional information, not that all information has now been gathered.  And all it really says is that enough people are unhappy enough (which may be composed of many who voted against them originally) to sign a petition to start the recall.

Comment: @dan04 There are other systems that use "instant runoffs", too, though, like [Contingent vote](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Contingent_vote) and [Supplementary vote](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Supplementary_vote). The most specific name would be "single-winner Hare's method" or something like that.  (And the non-instant version described by Ted is called [Exhaustive ballot](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Exhaustive_ballot))

Comment: "It's as fair and balanced as any other first-past-the-post ballot".  Or, in other words: **not** fair and **not** balanced.  You can express your 1st, 2nd, and 3rd choices on the ballot, but some voter's expressed preferences will have an effect on the outcome, while others will be discarded.  Condorcet ranked choice systems are more fair because they use all voters' preferences simultaneously to choose the winner.

Comment: @endolith everyone's preferences have an effect all the time. If half of the eventual second place's voters hadn't voted for them, they'd have been eliminated in an early round.

Comment: @Caleth If you vote A > B > C, and B is eliminated first, your preference for B > C is never counted.  A supermajority of voters may have expressed B > C on their ballots, but C can still win, because those expressed preferences are ignored by the elimination rule, and have no effect on the outcome. This does not happen under Baldwin's method, for comparison, which uses the same process but a different elimination rule.

Comment: @endolith For that electorate with a majority of `B > C` to elect `C`, there must also be a majority of `C > A`.

Comment: @Caleth What's your point?  The electorate prefers B > C > A.  Why should C win?  (In fact, the electorate might prefer F > G > H > I > J > B > C > A, yet C can still win under this system.)

Comment: @endolith no, `B > C` and `C > A` does not imply `B > A`. In that eventuality, a concordet method doesn't return a result (or returns an arbitrary one)

Comment: @Caleth It's not implied; I am specifying that the electorate prefers `B > C > A`, with no cycles, and yet Hare RCV elects C.  Or the electorate prefers `F > G > H > I > J > B > C > A`, with no cycles, and yet Hare RCV elects C.

Answer (score 21):

**It's mathematically sound**. It may seem as if checking the second-place votes of other "losing" candidates besides the last might give different winners, but it won't.

You're thinking we could have candidates A, B, C and D (in order of vote totals) where eliminating D could make A win, but eliminating C could make B win:

```
A <- D (all D's 2nd choice is A) adds to >50% 
B <- C (All C's 2nd choice is B) adds to >50%
```

That would be a possibly unfair situation, except it's impossible. The votes add to more than 100%. Put another way, if the last place being eliminated could make someone else win (be over 50%), then no one else can possibly win (they can't also get over 50%). No matter what order you go in, you'll have to eliminate D and check their 2nd place choices. Similar math works with groups -- say you eliminate candidates Z, then Y, X, W ... and their 2nd choices put C over the top. That's >50%, which means eliminating D through V couldn't have made anyone else win anyway.

There is possible funny business, but with "compromise candidates". Suppose we have votes for A(40%), B(39%) and C(21%) and everyone's 2nd choice is C (C voters have no 2nd choice). So 100% of the voters think C isn't too bad. But our system eliminates C, which removes those votes from the total, making A the winner even though 60% of the voters hate A. But that's a whole different animal, and it's not as if C could win with any system we have now.

Comment: "It's mathematically sound." According to Arrow's theorem, it's not entirely sound.

Comment: That's why the last Para is there. With respect to the Q, the system is sound. But if you step back and say "hey, we have all this extra info we never had before -- can we make up new definitions of fair that weren't possible before and solve for them?" things get complicated.

Comment: @Acccumulation according to Arrow's theorem, Kenneth Arrow was an unsatiable nitpicker.

Comment: I think this is the best answers so far. While other answers are interesting and informative, they talk in general about ranked-choice voting without addressing specifically the OP's question whether it gives too much weight to "the ones who voted for the least popular candidate" (compared to, e.g. the second to last etc).

Comment: @Acccumulation if you put an answer that relates this to Arrow's theorem, I'll upvote it.

Comment: @LucaCiti Most of StackExchange is like that. The first poster wants to answer a slightly different Q than was asked. Reading that influences the next person's understanding of the Q, and pretty soon people are just "answering the answers" without even realizing.

Answer (score 11):

> What's the rationale for giving that group disproportionate power in choosing the winning candidate?

There is no rationale, because RCV was never designed to give voters equal power.

Ranked Choice Voting (also known as *[Instant-Runoff Voting](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Instant-runoff_voting)*, *the Alternative Vote*, or *preferential voting*) is essentially a mistake: a misapplication of the Single Transferable Vote system.

[Single Transferable Vote](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Single_transferable_vote) is a multi-winner voting system, [designed in the 1850s](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Single_transferable_vote#History_and_current_use) to elect entire slates of representatives at once.  It is primarily associated with [Thomas Hare](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Thomas_Hare_(political_scientist)), whose [intention was to make parliament more representative of minority viewpoints](https://www.google.com/books/edition/The_Election_of_Representatives/2mxfAAAAcAAJ?hl=en&gbpv=1&bsq=%22every%20detail%20of%20this%20scheme%22&dq=%22Every%20detail%20of%20this%20scheme%22%20converges%20to%20one%20central%20point%2C%E2%80%94that%20of%20making%20the%20exercise%20of%20the%20suffrage%20a%20step%20in%20the%20elevation%20of%20the%20individual&pg=PR19&printsec=frontcover):

> Every detail of this scheme converges to one central point,—that of making the exercise of the suffrage a step in the elevation of the individual character, whether it be found in the majority or the minority. I disclaim for it, therefore, the title of a representation of minorities.

The idea is that after one candidate has been elected, the voters who supported that candidate with their first preferences are now well-represented in parliament, and their further preferences should no longer have weight.  The desires of other, unrepresented voters are now given more weight, so that they too have a good representative, and after repeating this process to fill every seat, parliament has good representation of a variety of viewpoints.

The first candidate elected is not intended to be a representative of the entire electorate, but only of the largest faction, and the representativeness of the body is achieved by electing further candidates of different ideologies.

STV does not lead to strict [proportional representation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Proportional_representation) of parties, in the way that systems like [party list](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Party-list_proportional_representation) do, but it typically produces a closer approximation than [FPTP](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/First-past-the-post_voting).

RCV/IRV was then "invented", possibly mistakenly, in 1871 by [William Ware](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/William_Robert_Ware), who was introducing Hare's method to Harvard.  [He describes Hare's method in detail](https://www.google.com/books/edition/Journal_of_Social_Science/W7QRAAAAYAAJ?hl=en&gbpv=1&pg=PA192&printsec=frontcover), correctly explaining how it should be used for multi-winner elections, but, while listing the advantages of STV, [he says](https://www.google.com/books/edition/Journal_of_Social_Science/W7QRAAAAYAAJ?hl=en&gbpv=1&pg=PA197&printsec=frontcover):

> It is equally efficient whether one candidate is to be chosen, or a dozen.

It's not clear whether he fully understood the implications of using a multi-winner system to elect a single candidate, but this is cited as the first description of what we now call IRV or RCV.

So RCV applies exactly the same process as STV, but stops after a single candidate has been elected, meaning that they are not a good representative of the electorate as a whole, but only of a large faction.

Other voting systems were designed from the beginning with single-winner elections in mind, and do a better job of representing the electorate as a whole.

For example, [Condorcet](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Marquis_de_Condorcet)'s "ranked choice" system considers all voters' preferences simultaneously when deciding the winner, not discarding some and keeping others like RCV does. It is able to elect a candidate who is preferred by the voters over all other candidates, even if not the first choice of many. Other "[Condorcet-compliant systems](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Condorcet_method)" try to achieve the same goal while reducing incentives for strategy, etc.

Likewise, the more recently-invented [cardinal voting systems](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cardinal_voting) like [STAR](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/STAR_voting), [Score](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Range_voting), or [Approval](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Approval_voting) voting try to find the candidate who has the highest overall approval/consent/utility, meaning they are the best representative of the electorate overall, or would make the voters happiest as a whole.

Comment: Love your answer endolith.  If people want to read about how Hare RCV messed up in Burlington Vermont in 2009 by failing to elect the majority candidate and failing to protect from the spoiler effect, please read [this paper](https://drive.google.com/file/d/1hh0kWBn7LzxkHkJ_r6FsDyBNmnjC7x4o/view).

Comment: Except the cardinal methods, suck, endolith.  Every voter is faced with the burden of tactical voting the minute they get into the voting booth with either Score (incl. STAR) or Approval.  How much should they *score* or *approve* of their 2nd choice candidate?

Comment: @robertbristow-johnson Cardinal methods collect more information than ordinal methods and are better at finding the candidate who is the best representative of the will of the voters.  Human desires are inherently cardinal, but ordinal methods quantize this into equally-spaced steps, arbitrarily assigning equal weights to preferences that are not equal, distorting the outcome.  Gibbard showed that all voting systems are subject to strategy, but cardinal systems typically don't have as much of a problem with it.

Comment: endolith, Cardinal methods immediately and simply place an obvious burden of tactical voting on voters that have a second-favorite candidate by forcing them to decide what to do with their second-favorite candidate.  and Score Voting violates the principle of One-Person-One-Vote.  If I enthusiastically prefer Candidate A and you prefer Candidate B only tepidly, because we are an equal citizens with franchise, your vote for B should count no less (nor more) than my vote for A.

Comment: @robertbristow-johnson All voting systems place a burden of tactical voting on the voter, but cardinal systems allow us to express our true preferences.  If you enthusiastically prefer A > B, and I am indifferent between them, forcing me to choose A>B or B>A at random is undemocratic, and my weak (actually nonexistent) preference should not be given the same weight as yours.  The goal is to find the candidate that best represents the voters.  Rejecting indifference and discarding strength of preference information makes that less likely.

Comment: //*"All voting systems place a burden of tactical voting on the voter"*//  Not such an obvious and immediate burden.  Just because all voting systems can find situations in which strategic voting (which is deliberately gaming the system) may be incentivized does not mean that all systems are equally burdensome regarding low-level tactical voting.  Ranked systems are **far, far** less tactical than cardinal systems.  And it's because it is plain that the voter has to consider tactics regarding whether to Approve or how high to Score their second choice.  Not so with ranked ballots.

Comment: @robertbristow-johnson That it's immediate and obvious is a strength, not a weakness.  The effects of strategy under ordinal systems is not obvious, leading to pathologies like the Dark Horse candidate winning because everyone thought they had no chance and ranked them second.  But regardless of strategy, ordinal systems are just inherently less democratic and more likely to lead to dysfunctional government.

Comment: @robertbristow-johnson For example, if you love Chocolate ice cream and hate Strawberry, while I and another friend love Chocolate almost as much as we love Strawberry, why should our slight preference for S>C outweigh your strong preference for C>S?  C is clearly the most representative candidate, making all voters very happy.  Choosing the Condorcet winner S would be undemocratic, as it makes 1/3 of the voters very unhappy. Assigning equal weights to unequal preferences is arbitrary and unfair.

Comment: because @endolith, we are partisans, not objective judges of figure skating at the Olympics.  but our partisanship is constrained by the principle that we are equal citizens with franchise and both have equal rights and an equal influence on government.  This is commonly called "**One-Person-One_Vote**".

Comment: @robertbristow-johnson You agree that, given the scenario I described, Chocolate would be the correct winner, no?  A candidate that every voter likes very much is better than a candidate that 2/3 of voters like very much but 1/3 hates very much.

Comment: again, @endolith, Utilitarianism is not the same as Majoritarianism.  in a democracy our rights are equal and our right to influence government is equal to anyone else's right to influence government (at least anyone else with franchise).  how much our vote counts is determined **only** by our franchise and not on some contrived measure of utility.  even if i tepidly like my candidate and you enthusiastically support yours, i do not grant to you nor sacrifice any value of my vote.  my tepid vote counts just as much as your enthusiastic vote.

Comment: @robertbristow-johnson Do you believe that Tideman and Schulze's methods violate 1P1V because they allow for the expression of indifference?

Comment: no.  because when the smoke and dust clear, we will be counting a quantity of persons having franchise and comparing that to another quantity of persons having franchise.  if their votes count equally the larger quantity of persons will have their will prevail.  But if the smaller quantity of persons get to have their candidate elected, that must mean that their votes count for more.

Comment: @robert bristow-johnson "One person, one vote" suggests that each voter should submit 1 ballot and that all ballots should be weighted equally. In the context of the US supreme court, it was invoked to correct an imbalance resulting from state congressional districts varying wildly in size, giving less proportional weight to voters from large districts.
The principle has to do with how ballots are weighted, not how they are marked (e.g. ordinal vs cardinal).
It certainly is not intended to mean that ballots must prohibit voters from differentiating between strong and weak preferences.

Comment: @eclipz905, I know that the, in the case law, *"One person, one vote"* is about redistricting and making sure that people are equally represented in legislative districts.  That's why I say "[t]his is commonly called **'One-Person-One_Vote'**." when I apply the term to voters, their ballots, and voting systems. It reflects how people should and do feel about the ballot that they cast. And it also means that, when we count votes, whatever the method is, that we're counting ***people***, not marks for their own sake. Marks on ballots do not have equal rights but people (with franchise) do.

Comment: So, whatever the voting system is, when the smoke and dust clear and you have Candidate A and Candidate B (there may be more candidates than only A and B) and a larger crowd of ***people*** are surrounding and supporting Candidate A than the size of the crowd surrounding and supporting Candidate B, then if B were somehow elected, *no matter **what** the method and rule is*, then the voters surrounding and supporting B somehow had votes that have more juice than the voters surrounding A.  Those voters had votes that each **counted for more** than the votes from the larger crowd supporting A.

Comment: @robertbristow-johnson There's no difference between a voting system that uses ordinal ballots and allows for the expression of indifference or incomplete rankings vs one that uses cardinal ballots and allows for the expression of strong/weak/indifferent preferences.  Both have some ballots "counted for more" than others, by your definition.

Comment: @endolith i think there's a difference.  cardinal ballots are about scoring candidates.  ordinal ballots only say who you prefer over who else.  Condorcet does not mind equal ranking of candidates (except for BTR) but the idea with the ranked ballot is simply: If Candidate A is ranked higher than Candidate B, then that is a vote for A in a race involving just A and B.  It doesn't matter how many levels A is ranked higher than B, it counts as one vote.  Cardinal is different.

Comment: Consider these four candidates: 1.Gandhi, 2.Mother Teresa, 3.Stalin, 4.Satan.  Now with ranked ballots it just means that the voter likes Mother Teresa better than Stalin.  If the race was between the two of them, that voter's vote goes to Mother Teresa.  But if it were Score Voting (or ranked ballot using Borda), the difference of preference between Gandhi and Teresa is the same between Teresa and Stalin.  But the voter might not feel that way about it.  The ranked ballot assigns no quantitative degree of difference of preference.  Only the polarity.

Comment: @robertbristow-johnson Exactly. My preference for Gandhi over Mother Teresa is not nearly as strong as my preference for Mother Teresa over Stalin.  Why should they be assigned the same weight?  That would result in undemocratic outcomes that don't truly represent the will of the voters.

Comment: but @endolith, we may like Gandhi and Mother Teresa a lot more than we like Stalin or Satan, but in a democracy, the ***people*** (with franchise) who like Stalin or Satan count just as much as you and me. No matter how misguided or deplorable they are.  They may be thinking ***we're*** the deplorables. The point is with Score voting (and with Borda, using a ranked ballot), if you rank them 1, 2, 3, 4 in that order, you are saying that your preference for Gandhi over Teresa is just as strong as your preference of Teresa over Stalin. Now, with a ranked ballot, it doesn't matter (except Borda).

Comment: The ***ONLY*** thing that should matter is, if you prefer Gandhi over Teresa and the election boils down to a race between the two, all of your voter power is directed to elect Gandhi. The method should provide ***no*** incentive for you to try to bury Teresa in order to help you elect your favorite candidate. If the method *does* make your vote for Gandhi more effective by burying Teresa, that might backfire if the race ends up between Teresa and Stalin and you helped Stalin get elected.

Answer (score 4):

Suppose people are voting on what topping they want on a pizza. Alice ranks the toppings [pepperoni, pineapple, olives, onions, anchovies]. Bob ranks them [anchovies, pepperoni, onions, olives, pineapple]. The first topping to be eliminated is anchovies, so in the second round of voting, Alice and Bob counted as voting for pepperoni. Neither of their votes count any more than the other. They are both one vote for pepperoni. And not only do they both get one full vote, but Alice's one full vote is going towards her first choice, while Bob's is going to his second choice, so in a way Bob is worse off than Alice.

There are situations where RCV leads to counter-intuitive results, but those situations are more complicated than just "the lowest ranked choice has their votes redistributed first".

Comment: One such situation where Hare RCV led to a bad result is [Burlington 2009](https://drive.google.com/file/d/1hh0kWBn7LzxkHkJ_r6FsDyBNmnjC7x4o/view).

Comment: here's a [newer better paper about Burlington 2009](https://drive.google.com/file/d/1jIhFQfEoxSdyRz5SqEjZotbVDx4xshwM/view?usp=sharing).

Answer (score 2):

Those voting for the least popular first-choice candidate don't have more power than anyone else. After that candidate gets eliminated, **it's exactly as if that candidate wasn't in the election at all** (not considering any psychological effects their presence in the election might have on voters or voters having fewer ranked choices than there are candidates). It's equivalent of no-one having voted for that candidate and moving subsequent candidates up one place in the ranking of anyone who voted for that candidate. If you do that, it should be clear that everyone is still on equal footing.

If voters have fewer ranked choices than there are candidates, this arguably means they now have strictly *less* power (not *more*), since they now have 1 fewer remaining choice than everyone else. The extreme result is that all their choices are eliminated early on and they don't get to influence the decision between the final two (or more) candidates. The less extreme result is that they need to compromise more in their choices to make it more likely to affect the final result (e.g. in a US election they'd probably always want one of their choices to include the Democratic or Republican candidate, as those are the most likely to be the final two candidates).

---

If anything, the voters whose *first choice* is popular (especially if it's one of the two most popular candidates) have more power.

They get to eliminate the least popular first-choice candidate even if that candidate is the most popular when you take the second or third choice of voters into account. Similarly for the least popular second-choice, third-choice, etc. candidates. They may also then get to influence the decision between the final two candidates, all just with a vote for one single candidate.

Although this is still less power than they'd have in single-choice/"regular" voting, since in that case the other voters who'd prefer a less popular candidate would actually get a voice in deciding between the two most popular candidates without having to vote strategically by not voting for the candidate they'd actually prefer.

Comment: //"After that candidate gets eliminated, **it's just as if that candidate wasn't in the election at all**."//

That is simply false, as [Burlington 2009 has shown](https://drive.google.com/file/d/1hh0kWBn7LzxkHkJ_r6FsDyBNmnjC7x4o/view).

Comment: @robertbristow-johnson It seems quite optimistic to assume anyone would read a 9-page document linked to in a comment. But, based on one or two paragraphs (correct me if I'm wrong) their point seems to be that the candidate who was eliminated first (Montroll) should've been elected. If so, then that would have no effect on the "it's just as if that candidate (Montroll) wasn't in the election at all" statement, which appears to still be 100% true in that election.

Comment: if you read the document, the Spoiler was Kurt Wright.  If Hare RCV fails to elect the Condorcet Winner, that election **must** be spoiled and whoever loses in the Hare RCV final round is the spoiler.  But you're right, Andy Montroll, the Condorcet Winner, should have been elected because he was the only **consistent** majority candidate.  To claim that Hare RCV **"guarantees"** a majority winner is a falsehood.  It did not elect the majority candidate in Burlington 2009.

Comment: @robertbristow-johnson I was only comparing ranked-choice voting with ranked-choice voting which excludes the least popular candidate. I wasn't making any claims about how that would compare to any other voting system nor whether it always elects the majority candidate.

Comment: the question is who is the least-popular candidate?  that can be a subtle question.

Comment: @robertbristow-johnson As per my answer, I'm referring to the candidate that's least popular based on the first choice of voters. And, again, this is only about ranked-choice voting; it's not in any way meant to make any claim whatsoever about whether this matches any other definition of "least popular".

Comment: //"... the candidate that's least popular based on the first choice of voters"//  And those of us advocating using ranked ballots are sooo convinced that solely the first choice of voters is the metric of the voter popularity of a candidate.

Comment: @robertbristow-johnson I'm not advocating for ranked ballots in this answer (rather just explaining one part of it) and I'm not making any assertion about what is or should be the metric of the popularity a candidate (I did use an unqualified "least popular" in a comment, but this was just a reference to "least popular first-choice candidate" that I used in my answer).

Answer (score 1):

By cutting the most losing candidate's votes out of the final results and redistributing them among their second choice candidates, it empowers the first choice votes of closer runner-ups.

---

The main benefit of redistributing the votes is to be able to check if Candidate A with a small minority advantage of votes over Candidate B isn't overriding the most preferred election results of the voters in the election.

If Candidates C and D are also in a close race, starting with Candidate E, if E is the lowest case voter, allows for a priority of consideration in determining who of Candidates B, C, and D would be most likely to be the next popular choice, if Candidate E's second choice votes don't confirm Candidate A's small lead into a larger lead. It's not actually empowering the lowest candidate's voting choice in influence, but instead empowering votes who didn`t make the threshold to be given enough influence to effect the results beyond the amounts they already, in cases where no candidate reached 50%, have yet to achieve.

By focusing on the votes that appear to have the lowest collection of effect on the election, their votes are allowed to avoid spoiling the election for another candidate because they weren't able to get full support of candidates that they aren't usually voting for.

Answer (score 1):

The reason is that those who support the least-favoured candidate are effectively disenfranchised under single-vote system, unless they vote strategically. It's not that they are suddenly given influence that they don't deserve; it's that they get back the influence they were previously missing.

Comment: Hello, welcome to Politics! Please check out the [tour] and the [help].